# Where to get purple rocket launchers?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I am trying to get a purple rarity rocket launcher so I can grind the Badaboom in the grinder, where can I find one? I have tried attacking the secret boss in the lava fall, but I haven't yet found a purple rarity rocket launcher. I have also tried to grind a purple launcher but I haven't had any luck.

I will probably need more than one of them because I might not find the legendary rocket launcher on the first try of grinding.

Comment: I haven't played BL:TPS for quite some time, so I won't answer with authority, but if I recall correctly, there weren't any specific way to get Rocket Launchers. You basically have to grind whatever place gets you average better loot faster, and wait. Iwajira is one such place.

Comment: Could always try your luck with the golden chest in Concordia.

Comment: Purple Equipment is 100% drop from Golden Key Chest

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the Pre-Sequel the grinding for weapons became quite different from the previous games.

The best chances to get above blue rarity weapons is raiding the bosses, especifically those that have an easy strategy such as Iwajira and Red Belly, and by looting the moonstone chests.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried farming nel? I got the purple rarity rocket launcher from the secret lava fall boss but i had to kill him alot or theres alway the sentinal  in the vault